# Xamarin Evolve - Solution Explorer error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using `MSVS 2015 Pro` with `Xamarin` (I'm new with `Xamarin`). I just downloaded `Xamarin Evolve` project. Then on the solution explorer, for the `Android` target, I get the error: `The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information` as you can see on the following image.

[image]

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: did you try right-click on the project and select "Reload"?

Comment: Thanks, that worked!